# Analytic function $f,$ such that $f(0) = 1$ and $f'(z) = zf(z),$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analyticity

I'm trying to find an example of an analytic function $f$ satisfying the IVP 
$$
f'(z) = z\,f(z), \quad
f(0) = 1, 
$$
and for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, but I'm somewhat at a loss of the best way to proceed.

Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about $f(z)=e^{\frac{1}{2}z^2}$?

Comment: Yep, that seems to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that
$$
f'(z)=zf(z)\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,\mathrm{e}^{-z^2/2}\big(f'(z)-zf(z)\big)=0
\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,\big(\mathrm{e}^{-z^2/2}f(z)\big)'=0,
$$
and thus $\mathrm{e}^{-z^2/2}f(z)$ is constant. In particular
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-z^2/2}f(z)=\mathrm{e}^{-0^2/2}f(0)=1,
$$
and thus
$$
f(z)=\mathrm{e}^{z^2/2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Can you solve this ODE?: $y'=xy, y(0)=1\,.$

Comment: How does restating the question help?

Comment: It's not a restatement of the question. This is typically among the first class of ODEs people learn to solve, I thought perhaps the OP didn't think of it like this.